# Group array objects by their value - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to figure the best way to group an array into multiple arrays based upon some operation on the array valuesю

For example, my array looks like

```
var arr = [100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 700, 1000, 1100, 1200]
```

I need to group the above array into different arrays as soon as the difference is more than 100.

So my output would look like:

```
var result = [[100, 200, 300], [500, 600, 700], [1000, 1100, 1200]]
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I have tried the conventional for loop with if conditions checking the difference between the next element with the current one, keep pushing it to an array and when the difference is more than 100 create a new array.

I feel there needs to be a better way to do it.

EDIT:-

I have tried the below code, its close but incomplete. Didn't spend further time on it as i was trying to get a simpler version using reduce or underscore -

```
var result = [], temp = [], difference;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
 if (difference !== (array[i + 1] - array[i])) {
    if (difference !== undefined) {
        result.push(temp);
        temp = [];
    }
    difference = array[i + 1] - array[i];
}
temp.push(array[i]);
}

if (temp.length) {
  result.push(temp);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you've written to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, just edited. Its incomplete, stopped spending further time on it as i was looking for a simpler solution using reduce or underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to accomplish this.

```
var arr = [100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 700, 1000, 1100, 1200];

var groups = arr.reduce(function (a, b) {
  if (a.length === 0) { // First Iteration
    a.push([b]);
    return a;
  }

  var lastGroupIndex = a.length - 1;
  var lastGroup = a[lastGroupIndex];

  var lastElementIndex = lastGroup.length - 1;
  var lastElement = lastGroup[lastElementIndex];

  if (b - lastElement <= 100) { // Add to current group
    lastGroup.push(b);
    return a;
  }

  a.push([b]); // Create new group
  return a;
}, [])
```

Note: This solution does not use ES6 features. I made an assumption from the use of `var` in the initial question that the codebase was not on ES6 and in comments it came to light that this assumption was correct.

Comment: The question assumes that the array is sorted doesn't it? The goal is to literally split if next element is more than 100 greater than the old element.

Comment: yeah I'm not sure

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. Your answer is nice too :). Since the question states that the previous solution used a for loop, I'm assuming that no sorting is desired.

Comment: I was doing the same but with some es6 tricks to make it shorter: wrap the reduce in a function with signature `function group([first, ...rest])` and then initialize the reduce with `[[first]]` and reduce only `rest`

Comment: Since the question used `var` instead of `let` to declare the array, I wrote it without using any ES6 niceness on the assumption that the user may not be on ES6.

Comment: @Nathan, thanks. Yes the array is already sorted. and yeah codebase is not ES6 compatible yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question.

Edit: after re-reading it's not clear that the input array is sorted or not. If it is sorted, you can just look at the reduce call.

At first, I was wondering if there's a more optimal solution than O(nlogn). However, even though you are bucketing items, the final mega-array is still fully-sorted. Therefore, if there exists a way faster of O(nlogn) to solve your problem, you could also solve sorting faster than nlogn.

Given that, the most straightforward solution is to sort the array, and then partition it accordingly to the last element as you iterate through it. `Reduce` ends up being a perfect tool here:

```js
const input = [100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 700, 1000, 1100, 1200];

const sorted = input.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b);

const buckets = sorted.reduce((buckets, item, i) => {
  const lastBucket = buckets[buckets.length - 1];
  if (i === 0) {
    return [[item]];
  }
  const prev = sorted[i - 1];
  if (item - prev > 100) {
    buckets.push([item]);
  } else {
    buckets[buckets.length - 1].push(item);
  }
  return buckets;
}, [])
console.log(buckets);
```

Comment: The question doesn't state that sorting is desired.

Answer (score 0):

As there was no answer using the full aruments of reduce, in one function:

```
var arrOrg = [100, 200, 300, 500, 600, 700, 1000, 1100, 1200]
arrOrg.reduce(function (acc, item, idx, arr) {
  if (idx) {
    (idx < arr.length && arr[idx + 1] > item + 100) // the spec condition
      ? acc[acc.length] = [item]
      : acc[acc.length - 1].push(item)
  } else acc[0][0] = item
  return acc
}, [[]])
```

Note it returns an

```
[[]]
```

when called with an empty array, shouldn´t it?

Also note it does not care about sorting.